# Is there a simple To Do app that works on iPhone, iPad, and Macbook Pro?

Tags: macos, ios, software-recommendation

I am looking for a simple To Do or Task app that will sync across iPhone, iPad and Macbook Pro automatically.

What app will do this?

Answer (score 6):

Most people are looking to choose between the hundreds of Apps that exist in this class.

For most, you can't beat the free [Reminders app with iCloud syncing](http://www.macworld.com/article/1164792/how_to_use_the_ios_reminders_app.html).

It really boils down to what you call simple and how you work. Some find the simple design of [Cheddar](https://cheddarapp.com) or [Clear](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/clear/id504544917?mt=12) to be great while others dislike them strongly. You could easily spend more than $100 for a best of class solution like [OmniFocus](http://www.omnigroup.com/products/omnifocus/) or [Things](http://culturedcode.com/things/)

If the free reminders app (in conjunction with iCloud's notes and calendar integration), then you can have some more specific requirements from which to choose from the many, many other solutions from the App Store (as most of the apps in this class have adopted the Mac App store and iOS App Store as there is little downside for them to comply with the requirements of sandboxing and code signing).

Answer (score 3):

Reminders.  It's built into OS X and iOS.  It syncs via iCloud.

Answer (score 1):

[Wunderlist](http://www.6wunderkinder.com/wunderlist) rocks, but lately, I've been using the Notes App more and more - simple, syncs, and provided by Apple

Comment: Wunderlist is fantastic, and also has a great web interface and a Windows client

Comment: Wunderlist syncing sucks, and graphics are way too heavy on eye when dealing with a larger number of items on mobile.

Answer (score 0):

[Buddy Bird Todo](http://www.buddybirdtodo.com). It syncs seamlessly via iCloud and Toodledo. Text to speech feature makes it unique also. It is one of the few apps which reads out your task to you. Omnifocus and Things are some of the other good todo apps..But they are quite expensive.